# PL or projective PL map on the links of a PL manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a PL manifold and $f: M\rightarrow M$ be a PL homeomorphism. Suppose that $f(x)=x$ for some vertex $x$. Is the restriction map of $f$ on the links of $x$ also PL? Someone claims that this is only a piecewise projective linear map. I don't know why (maybe, I didn't get the right statement). Any references or explanations will be welcomed.